# declaring generic type object in go

Tags: object, go

Is there a generic type `Object` in golang similar to other languages that can be assigned any kind of payload?

```
type Foo struct {
    data object
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All Go types implement the empty interface `interface{}`.

```
type Foo struct {
   data interface{}
}
```

The empty interface is covered in  [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/14), [The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) and the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

Answer (score 5):

Starting in Go 1.18 you can use `any` — alias of `interface{}` as type of field or variable. It looks better than `interface{}`.

```
type Foo struct {
   data any
}
```

Or also you can design the struct as accepting a type parameter. This way it becomes truly generic:

```
type Foo[T any] struct {
   data T
}
```

Usage:

```
foo := Foo[string]{data: "hello"}
```

The main difference is that `Foo` values without type parameter can be compared using `==` and `!=` with other `Foo` values, and yield true or false based on the actual fields. *The type is the same!* — In case of `interface{}`/`any` fields, it will compare the values stored in there. Instances of `Foo[T any]` instead can NOT be compared *with compilation error*; because using different type parameters produces different types altogether — `Foo[string]` is not the same type as `Foo[int]`. Check it here -> https://go.dev/play/p/zj-kC0VvlUH?v=gotip